# PHP regex and preg_replace issue 3

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i want to transform this :

```
$text='{i:0;s:8:"Par mail";}';
```

to :

```
$text="Par mail";
```

and

$text='{i:0;s:8:"Par mail";i:1;s:7:"Par fax";}';

to :

$text="Par mail | Par fax";

And others to the 4th expression

For this I use the PHP function `preg_replace`

```
$text = preg_replace('/{i:[^\\[]?;s:[^\\[]?:"(.*?)";i:[^\\[]?;s:[^\\[]?:"(.*?)";/}','"$1 | $2"', $text);
```

I need some help, the enter format must be exact for transform the text.
Cordially

Comment: .... What happens? What doesn't work as expected? What do you get instead of what you expect?

Comment: looks like a serialized array, where did you get that anyway?

Comment: the {i:0;s:8:"...";i:1;s:7:"...";} format must be selected because it's a little part of long text.

Comment: Can`t you just keep the full unserialized string, serialize it and than  implode like this: `implode(unserialize($text), ' | ')` ? For this you`ll need an "a:2:" at the beginning of the text. Just askin`

Answer (score 0):

Use `[^"]*` instead of `.*?`

```
{i:[^\\[]*?;s:[^\\[]*?:"([^"]*)";i:[^\\[]*?;s:[^\\[]*?:"([^"]*)";}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gH7pG6/2)

```
<?php
$string = '{i:0;s:8:"Par mail";i:1;s:7:"Par fax";}';
$pattern = '~{i:[^\\[]*?;s:[^\\[]*?:"([^"]*)";i:[^\\[]*?;s:[^\\[]*?:"([^"]*)";}~';
$replacement = "$1 | $2";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Output:

```
Par mail | Par fax
```

Comment: @matthughs can there be only 2 `Par` or more.If its more this will not work.

Comment: It's true, if have more expression that will not work,i edit my first question

Comment: Then why you said that it's an exact string format?

Answer (score 0):

I went down the `preg_replace_callback` route.

```
<?php

$s = '{i:0;s:8:"Par mail";i:1;s:7:"Par fax";}';

$arrM = array();
preg_replace_callback("/(s\:[0-9]*\:\")([A-Z\ ]+)/i", function($arrMatches) use(&$arrM) {
   $arrM[] = $arrMatches[2];
}, $s);

echo implode(" | ", $arrM);  //Output: Par mail | Par fax
```

https://eval.in/194049

Answer (score 0):

I guess your string has these characters before it: `a:2` and then can be unserialized:

```
$text='a:2:{i:0;s:8:"Par mail";i:1;s:7:"Par fax";}';
$obj = unserialize($text);
print_r($obj);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Par mail
    [1] => Par fax
)
```

After this unserialization you can join the values with `|`.

```
echo implode('|', $obj);// --> Par mail|Par fax
```